# Scrolling with a styled unordered list (select box replacement)

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, drop-down-menu

My company had a website we're working on redone by a designer. It looks much better, but I've hit a snag implementing their design in HTML+CSS. They have a heavily styled `<select>` box, so much so that I couldn't recreate it with pure CSS. I found [a solution](http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect2/) that uses Javascript to replace the `<select>` box with a `<ul>`. This works almost perfectly, but there are two problems with it:

1. It doesn't scroll when there are many elements.
2. It doesn't close when you click outside of the dropdown.

I've played around with it in Firebug, but becuase the `<li>`s are styled with `display:block`, they don't seem to be contained by the surrounding `<ul>`, which means I can't set a maximum height.

Issue #2 is not as important, but it would be nice to know how to fix that as well.

Here's a link to the problem page: http://www.truwindshield.com/test2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery and the solution isn't, you could consider replacing it with a relevant jQuery plugin. This one seems to be working and degrading nicely: [jQuery SelectBox](http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/)

This implementation also solves the two issues you're having and might save you some working trying to hack the other solution into doing what you want it to.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with, and I forgot to mark as answered. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is another solution I came across recently, which styles every form element: http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/